# Google Cloud Vision image matching in specific domain

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Given a particular image, I'd like to be able to use Google Cloud Vision Web Detection to search for partial matches (`partialMatchingImages`) within a particular website, rather than the entire web, as is the default behavior.

I'm trying to get similar behavior as when you Search by Image in Google Images, upload an image, and type "site:nytimes.com" (for example) in the search bar.

Is this possible with the Google Cloud Vision API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I've investigated in the official documentation for [current](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web#vision-web-detection-python) and [beta features](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/cloud-client/web). It doesn't seem it is possible yet to do a search for a specific website with the Cloud Vision API.

The [examples](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/beta-web-entities#vision-beta-web-detection-gcs-python) given in from the official documentation also it doesn't seem possible to have any reference towards such functionality either.

There is a request going in the [public issue tracker of google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72421411), although they still have to answer it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! (even if it's not, of course, what I was hoping for)

Comment: Bumping this up again!! Is there any update wrt this?