# How can I use Google cloud vision api for web detection to detect pages from a specific website?

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to limit searches within a specific site by using google cloud vision web detection api. Like, we can specify site:example.com for google search. I want to use this feature using cloud vision api.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If so, any hints about that, please?

Comment: Bumping this up again. Any updates here?

Comment: No luck apparently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942150/google-cloud-vision-image-matching-in-specific-domain